# Does setting a quality of service have any effect on a serial DispatchQueue?

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

It’s possible to create a serial DispatchQueue that has a quality-of-service setting:

```
let myQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "my-cool-queue",
                            qos: .utility)
```

However, all of the documentation I can find mentions QoS only in the context of selecting one of the global dispatch queues. (The `DispatchQueue` initializer, unfortunately, is [not documented at all](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/2300059-init) past the fact that it exists!) Is it meaningful to specify a quality of service on a serial queue, or does each such queue just execute every task as soon as possible after the previous task is finished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It surely has effect when your (serial) queue is targeting another queue. Watch this talk:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/706/

At around 20:46, he is talking about forming trees of DispatchQueues. The QoS matters in that case.

Answer (score 2):

The QoS in independent from the queue type, serial or concurrent:

The QoS of a dispatch queue is used by GCD to prioritize the backing posix threads that eventually run the enqueued work items.

The concurrency model isthing to determine if the jobs may run independently from each other or not. It does not give any hint about how much "attention" the backing thread(s) get from the OS scheduler.

So to answer your closing question: A serial queue executes the work items one after the other, as fast as the QoS allows.